# Are paying tax vouchers required?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I am 23, so I am pretty new at paying taxes, so sorry for another dumb question I have been unable to answer.

With much distress I finished my taxes, but what are estimated payments on next years taxes? According to turbotax, I need to pay a schedule of 4 vouchers.

Is this required or recommended? I'd rather just pay it all at once when the time comes if that is an option. I've never had to do this before.

```
Mail payments according to the schedule below:
|
| Voucher Number Due Date Amount
| 1 04/15/2013 $ 339.00
| 2 06/17/2013 $ 339.00
| 3 09/16/2013 $ 339.00
| 4 01/15/2014 $ 339.00
```

|

Comment: Did you owe money to the IRS this tax season? Was there a penalty?

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is required, but with these amounts the underpayment penalty will be relatively small - I tried calculating the penalty on $1356 using the [current form 2210](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f2210.pdf) and came up with $25 penalty.

If you're a W2 employee - you can just adjust your withholding using [form W4](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-W-4,-Employee%27s-Withholding-Allowance-Certificate-1) (which you need to give to your payroll representative), instead of using estimate payment vouchers, to cover for all your yearly taxes.

Comment: I am a w-2 employee. How do I adjust these?

Comment: Use form W4. Read the instructions, use the worksheets on it to calculate the numbers, and when done - fill it and give to your HR/Payroll representative. http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-W-4,-Employee%27s-Withholding-Allowance-Certificate-1

Comment: @Swim If I remember correctly, TurboTax has a feature to calculate the W4 for you as well, look it up there.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [comprehensive article](http://blogs.hrblock.com/2013/01/14/how-to-change-your-w-4-withholding-to-maximize-your-tax-refund/) on the W4 and how it works. The bottom line is once you know your tax bracket, you'll know how much tax one withholding allowance impacts you. You'll likely need to drop your withholding by 2 or 3 allowances. Or you can just add about $25 per week on another line of the W4.

Answer (score 1):

When you owe more than $1000 in taxes, turbo tax will print out the payment vouchers based on estimated tax in an attempt to make sure you don't have a penalty next year.

Non-lawyer speak: Your responsibility is to pay most of the taxes you owe in the quarter within which you earned the money.

Turbo Tax is recommending estimated tax payments to do that.   JoeTaxpayer is recommending changing your W4.   When I found this happening to me I went with JoeTaxpayer and upped my withholding.

According to the IRS, in order to avoid an under-withholding penalty you need to do the following:

> Generally, most taxpayers will avoid this penalty if they owe less
> than $1,000 in tax after subtracting their withholdings and credits,
> or if they paid at least 90% of the tax for the current year, or 100%
> of the tax shown on the return for the prior year, whichever is
> smaller.
>
> [IRS Source](http://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc306.html)

Comment: There is also a separate rule for those whose income exceeds $150K or so. They must have paid 110% of the previous year's tax in order to avoid a penalty.  Similarly, somewhat different rules apply to farmers and fishermen.