# Does a total due tax of over $1000 automatically get placed in a quarterly payment plan?

Tags: united-states, taxes, contractor

I work as a contractor and I'm filing through TurboTax this year in the US.

I owe just over $1100 this year. I've always been in the green before this year - always received a refund.

The report that was generated just before I file has notes about due dates for payments, 4 equal payments spread 3 months apart.

I didn't select the payment plan option from Turbo Tax, and was expecting to have to pay the lump sum. (oh, I've been dreading it.)

If I continue with the file, will the IRS take the whole amount of the taxes or will they pull the amount from my checking account at those dates?

I recognize this is a green question - just looking for some basic reference material for my situation.

Turns out this question is very similar to this one: 
[Are paying tax vouchers required?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/21361/9344)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out I had misunderstood what those dates really were. They were estimated payments for next year's taxes, not this year's. IRS will take the full amount due **for 2012 taxes**
on April 15 when it is due. For 2013's taxes I have the option of paying in advance on a quarterly basis, or incurring a small penalty/fee and paying the full sum on April 15th next year.

Comment: @Chad It's my first year as a contractor, and I don't have any taxes withheld. I had no idea how the taxes would work at all. I assumed I'd owe but had no idea how much. I've got a better idea and plan to be more proactive about it for 2013.

Comment: @Nicholoas as  long as you pay at least the tax liability for the previous year with your withholding/estimate payments, you'll be fine and no penalties will be assessed (unless you're a really high-earner, but then you can afford a tax accountant to work for you).